# Adding image to Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have added a image file to my code in tkinter but it basically fills my the whole frame so if its possible can you recommend a tutorial that shows or explains how to do this.... unless you can show me on here.

I havent added my full code but the code below should display a test image once you have it saved in the python directory.

I would like to create 'next' button which would open up a new frame with another image on it.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
ButtonImage = PhotoImage(file='test.gif')
testButton = Button(root, image=ButtonImage)
testButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is concretely your problem? Make the button not to fill the whole window, or how to create a new window?

Comment: basically i would like to end up with a picture on the top half of the frame followed by some text underneath and some radio buttons and a next button to move onto the next slide.

i have made a frame with my buttons and text but i dont know how to add an image to the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
from Tkinter import *
from glob import glob

class ImageFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.images = glob("*.gif")
        self.cur = 0
        # label showing the image
        self.image = PhotoImage()
        imagelabel = Label(self, image=self.image)
        imagelabel.grid(row=1, column=1)
        # button cycling through the images
        button = Button(self, text="NEXT", command=self.show_next)
        button.grid(row=2, column=1)
        # layout and show first image
        self.grid()
        self.show_next()

    def show_next(self):
        self.cur = (self.cur + 1) % len(self.images)
        self.image.configure(file=self.images[self.cur])

ImageFrame().mainloop()
```

Some explanations:

- `glob` is used to get a list of all files matching some pattern in the current directory
- `grid` is a simple but quite flexible layout manager for Tkinter (see [Tkinter reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid.html))
- the `show_next` method, which is bound to the button, cycles through the images and binds a new image to the `PhotoImage` using `configure`

The result is a simple frame showing a large image and a button, cycling though the `gif` images in the current directory.

Comment: Your example code doesn't create an instance of `Tk`. Apparently that is happening automagically but best practice says you should explicitly create it. Also, your example will show poor resize behavior. Otherwise, it's a nice example of what the OP is looking for.

Comment: thats what im looking for :) can you explain what else it needs to make it best practice...

thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous modules that would help you out with this. You can use the PIL module. Typically what I would do in a situation like yours is use the PIL module to load and paste the image onto the frame. This is how you do this.

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
root = Tk()
Image       = Image.open(path).resize((300, 300)), Image.ANTIALIAS
ButtonImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image)
# If you are using image by itself. Without it being a button. 
#Image_Label = Label(image = self.HomeImage, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
# Otherwise 
testButton = Button(root, image=ButtonImage)
testButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I believe that this would definitely help you with resizing the image and loading an image to the screen as a button. We used PIL to load the image onto the frame and resized the image. This is What you were also asking for earlier. I used the resize method on the Image.open() Function. This resizes the image to what you want. The standards are the actual sizes of that image.