# Python show two images with the after-method

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter

I want to show two images successively like a slideshow in my stacked tkinter frame. I heard, that I can do that with the after-method, but how do I use this method? Sorry if my english is bad. Thanks.

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import sys
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
from functools import partial
import random

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title("test")
        self.state('zoomed')

        container= tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames={}
        for F in (fenster, mode1):
            frame= F(container, self)
            self.frames[F]=frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

            self.show_frame(fenster)

    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame=self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()

class fenster(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label=tk.Label(self, text="Das ist die Startseite")
        label.pack()

        button=tk.Button(self, text="Start",
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame(mode1))
        button.pack()

class mode1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label1=tk.Label(self, text=" ")
        label1.pack()

        def ok(label1):
            def do_a():
                image1 = PhotoImage(file = 'test.gif')
                photo1=Label(image=image1)
                photo1.image=image1
                photo1.pack()

                image2 = PhotoImage(file = 'tet.gif')
                photo2=Label(image=image2)
                photo2.image=image2
                photo2.pack()

            def do_b():
                print("ngfijnwgfekö")

            WORDS={"test1":do_a,
                   "test2":do_b}
            choice=random.choice(list(WORDS))
            label1['text']=choice
            WORDS[choice]()

        button1=tk.Button(self, text='Knopf', command=partial(ok, label1))
        button1.pack()

if __name__== "__main__":
    app=SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but this should get you going: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15382530/1639625 If you want to make an automatic slide show, just add `self.after(seconds, show_next)` at the end of `show_next`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you want to add the slide show to your code, so here's a minimal working example of a simple [Tkinter](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html) GUI, using [`after`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) to [cycle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) though all the images [found](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) in the current directory.

```
from Tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage, Label
from glob import glob
from itertools import cycle

# this method calls itself again after 1000 milliseconds
def show_next():
    image.configure(file=next(images))
    root.after(1000, show_next)

# cycle though gif images found in working directory
images = cycle(glob("*.gif"))

# build minimal test GUI
root = Tk()
image = PhotoImage()
Label(root, image=image).pack()

# start slide show and GUI main loop
show_next()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks it works really well. But what do I have to do, when I dont want to import all images?

Comment: @user3787859 Well, just put those images into the `images` list that you want, e.g. `images = cycle(["test.gif", "tst.img"])`. You could also use a generic file selection dialogue to populate that list...

Comment: Is there a way to do it wihtout cycle?

Comment: @Duardo Sure, just put all the images into a list, keep track of the index of the image you are currently displaying, and increase that index each time. Also make sure that you reset that index to 0 when you reach the end of the list. [Like here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15382530/1639625) However, I think using `cycle` is much easier here.